# ambiguous operator[] in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, variadic-templates, ambiguous

I'm trying to compile this example, where a variadic class template inherits from a variadic amount of bases, each of which implements a different `operator[]`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Field {
  typename T::value_type storage;

  typename T::value_type &operator[](const T &c) {
    return storage;
  }
};

template<typename... Fields>
struct ctmap : public Field<Fields>... {
};

int main() {
    struct age { typedef int value_type; };
    struct last_name { typedef std::string value_type; };

    ctmap<last_name, age> person;

    person[last_name()] = "Smith";
    person[age()] = 104;
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10), I get the following error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:23: error: request for member ‘operator[]’ is ambiguous
     person[last_name()] = "Smith";
                       ^
main.cpp:7:27: note: candidates are: typename T::value_type& Field<T>::operator[](const T&) [with T = main()::age; typename T::value_type = int]
   typename T::value_type &operator[](const T &c) {
                           ^
main.cpp:7:27: note:                 typename T::value_type& Field<T>::operator[](const T&) [with T = main()::last_name; typename T::value_type = std::basic_string<char>]
main.cpp:23:17: error: request for member ‘operator[]’ is ambiguous
     person[age()] = 104;
                 ^
main.cpp:7:27: note: candidates are: typename T::value_type& Field<T>::operator[](const T&) [with T = main()::age; typename T::value_type = int]
   typename T::value_type &operator[](const T &c) {
                           ^
main.cpp:7:27: note:                 typename T::value_type& Field<T>::operator[](const T&) [with T = main()::last_name; typename T::value_type = std::basic_string<char>]
```

Why is this ambiguous?

Comment: This is accepted by clang++3.8: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/huzwGp0kc2OafMZl (but I'm not sure which compiler is right in this case)

Comment: (Basically member functions in multiple base classes do not overload. I'm not sure how this interacts with operator lookup though; it seems at first glance that clang is wrong.)

Comment: You could make this compliant with a linear/tree based inheritance, and `using` declarations.

Comment: is true dyp, I try this code in coliru with clang 3.6 and work fine, but I need to use gcc, in this case the version is 4.9.2.

Comment: Yakk, can you explain me how can I do a linear/tree base inheritance?, can you give some example?

Comment: @dyp I think clang bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A portable way do do what you want is roughly:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct operator_index_inherit {};
template<class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
struct operator_index_inherit<T0, T1, Ts...>:
  T0, operator_index_inherit<T1, Ts...>
{
  using T0::operator[];
  using operator_index_inherit<T1, Ts...>::operator[];
};
template<class T0>
struct operator_index_inherit<T0>:
  T0
{
  using T0::operator[];
};
```

then:

```
template<class... Fields>
struct ctmap : operator_index_inherit<Field<Fields>...> {
  using base = operator_index_inherit<Field<Fields>...>;
  using base::operator[];
};
```

here we linearly inherit from each of the types, and `using operator[]` on our parents.

If we could `using Field<Fields>::operator[]...;` we would not have to do this.

Some care has to be taken with constructors (which I did not take), but you might not need to do this.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4cd4c24d242631c).

---

What is actually going wrong depends on details of the standard I am less than certain of.  Basically, you are mixing operators and inheritance and overloading in a complex way.  Even if your code is standard compliant (which it may or may not be), it is compliant in a way that some compilers die on.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question tbh

Comment: WOW ... it's work, probably take me a while to fully understand your example (I'm not fully skilled on C++11 yet), thank you a lot

Comment: Then it's half there :)

Comment: Update: new syntax appears to support that, `template<class... T> struct S: T... { using T::operator[]...; };` (C++17) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Answer (score 2):

The code is invalid and gcc is correct to reject it (clang 3.6.0 accepts it though - this is a bug). The rules for looking up an operator start with, from [over.match.oper]:

> [...] for a binary
>   operator @ with a left operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is T1 and a right operand of a type
>   whose cv-unqualified version is T2, three sets of candidate functions, designated *member candidates*, *non-member
>   candidates* and *built-in candidates*, are constructed as follows:
>   — If T1 is a complete class type or a class currently being defined, the set of member candidates is the
>   result of the qualified lookup of `T1::operator@` (13.3.1.1.1); otherwise, the set of member candidates
>   is empty.

The lookup rules for a member name are (since we're looking up `ctmap<last_name,age>::operator[]`), from [class.member.lookup]:

> The lookup set for f in C, called S(f,C), [...] is calculated
>   as follows:
>
> If C contains a declaration of the name f, [...]
>
> Otherwise (i.e., C does not contain a declaration of f or the resulting declaration set is empty), S(f,C) is
>   initially empty. If C has base classes, calculate the lookup set for f in each direct base class subobject Bi,
>   and merge each such lookup set S(f,B<sub>i</sub>) in turn into S(f,C).
>
> The following steps define the result of merging lookup set S(f,B<sub>i</sub>) into the intermediate S(f,C):
>   — [...]
>   — Otherwise, if the declaration sets of S(f,B<sub>i</sub>) and S(f,C) differ, the merge is ambiguous: the new
>   S(f,C) is a lookup set with an invalid declaration set and the union of the subobject sets. In subsequent
>   merges, an invalid declaration set is considered different from any other.
>   — [...]

Basically - we have two base classes here, both with an `operator[]`. Both declaration sets differ - so the merge is ambiguous. The way to disambiguate would be to introduce *using-declaration*s bringing in all the base class member functions into the derived class, so that the initial lookup set finds everything.

To shorten your example:

```
struct A { void foo(char) { } };
struct B { void foo(int ) { } };

struct C : A, B { };

struct D : A, B {
    using A::foo;
    using B::foo;
};
```

With that hierarchy

```
C c;
c.foo(4);  // error: ambiguous lookup set for foo()

D d;
d.foo('x') // OK: calls A::foo()
```

Comment: I understand .... I have a question, How can I call B::foo()? ... I try to cast the "4", or declare a variable int but always give the ambiguous lookup.

Comment: @Trungus The arguments don't matter - it's the actual lookup of the name `foo` that fails because it's ambiguous. To call it, you need to have the *using-declaration* (`using B::foo` in the class). Or you could call it through a pointer to member (`(C{}.*&B::foo)(4);` <== don't write this code, I'm just including it for completeness)

Comment: correct me if I wrong but your example already have the "using B:foo" in the class declaration so, why still have the ambiguous lookup error?

Comment: @Trungus `D` has the `using`s, and has no errors. `C` omits them, and thus has errors.

Comment: How does this apply to operator lookup?  `[]`, or even free binary `operator*`?  The op is invoking an operator, not calling a method.  It may be dispatched to the method operator, but does it follow the exact same rules?

Comment: @Yakk It's still a name, no?

Comment: It is an operator.  Operator lookup is a mixture of overload resolution and member resolution.  Your argument is persuasive for member lookup: but [obviously operators are more than just member lookup](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13bc82aee4eca662).

Comment: [This one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bcc1368ddf58488) seems to indicate it is when there are two different member `operator*`s things break, and not before.  Which does make sense.  But clang disagrees.

Comment: @Yakk [over.match.oper] starts with building up the candidate set as "If T1 is a complete class type or a class currently being defined, the set of member candidates is the
result of the qualified lookup of T1::operator@ (13.3.1.1.1); otherwise, the set of member candidates
is empty." So we still follow the member lookup rules - but we just add the non-member ones that match as well.