# how to create a complex type using tuples and variadic templates

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, stdtuple, boost-tuples

In first place, I'm not a very skilled programmer in C++11 and templates, I read a lot of posts but I can't figure out how to write my idea (if is even possible), saying that, this is my idea.

My idea is create a complex compiler-time type, I'm trying to follow this rules

- Defined like a struct, I mean field by field (no syntax restrinctions), for example something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525445/ambiguous-operator-in-variadic-template).
- Each field type will be one of this types: int, short, long, byte, bool and std::string.
- And here is the tricky part, I want a tuple where each position will be a reference to each field, in this way I can access to the stored data field by field or get a tuple to it. I have no problem to use std::tuples or boost::tuples.

Every suggestion, example, advise and any other comment are welcome, I'm trying to learn how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Edit: I can give you the code where I trying to do this, perhaps is not the best aprouch so I'm open to suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

/* Trait Def */
template<typename T>
struct field_trait
{
    typedef T type;
    typedef type &ref;
    typedef type *pointer;
    typedef const type &const_ref;
};

/* Field Def */
template <typename T>
struct Field : field_trait<Field<T>>
{
    typedef typename T::type value_type;
    typedef typename Field<T>::type field_type;

    typename T::type storage;

    typename T::ref &operator[](const T &c)
    {
        return storage;
    };
};


/* Linear inheritance def */
template<class...Ts>
struct operator_index_inherit {};

template<class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
struct operator_index_inherit<T0, T1, Ts...> : T0, operator_index_inherit<T1, Ts...>
{
  using T0::operator[];
  using operator_index_inherit<T1, Ts...>::operator[];
};

template<class T0>
struct operator_index_inherit<T0>: T0
{
  using T0::operator[];
};

template<class... Fields>
struct bind : operator_index_inherit<Field<Fields>...> 
{
    using base = operator_index_inherit<Field<Fields>...>;
    using base::operator[];

    bind() : data(make_tuple(int(0),string("")))
    {};
    typedef std::tuple<typename Field<Fields>::value_type&... > tuple_t;
    tuple_t data;
};

/* Data type def */
struct t_age : field_trait<int>{};
struct t_name : field_trait<std::string>{};

typedef Field<t_age> age;

int main()
{
    bind<t_age,t_name> data;

    data[t_age()] = 123;
    data[t_name()] = "pepe";

    return 0;
}
```

This code don't compile, the error is caused by the declaration of type "tuple_t" and "tuple_t data"

Regards

Comment: No idea what you're asking. Can you provide a sample usage of such a thing?

Comment: I have to agree with Barry: it is unclear what you're asking here. Perhaps providing a (even non-working) minimal sample would make things more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess at what you're looking for, I've got a quick, crude example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <tuple>

class Type
{
public:
    Type() : t{std::tie(a, b, c, d, e, f)} {}

    int a;
    short b;
    long c;
    unsigned char d;
    bool e;
    std::string f;

    std::tuple<int&, short&, long&, unsigned char&, bool&, std::string&> t;
};

int main()
{
    Type A{};

    A.c = 5;

    std::cout << std::get<2>(A.t) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With a [demo](http://ideone.com/wpLGtu).

Comment: Hi R2, your example is clear and fully functional, but in my case I can't use it, because I need to declare a lot of class of this kind, so is a lot of work to do.